# Can I use two separate ODE call functions for a system of two differential equations in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, ode

I am trying to code a system of ODE's shown below.

[image: First quation]

[image: Second equation]

As seen, the second ODE completely depends on the value of the first ODE.
How can I code the second ode?
I am using ode45.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's quite possible. Define `x` as `[c;ce]`, then you have something like:

```
function dx = my_ode(t,x)

% parameters definition
kf = ...; % whatever value you are using
P0 = ...; % whatever value you are using
Jer = ...; % whatever value you are using
J_serca = ...; % whatever value you are using
gamma = ...; % whatever value you are using

% differential equations
dc = (kf*P0+Jer)*(x(2)-x(1)) - J_serca;
dce = -gamma*dc;
dx = [dc;dce];
```

and then you can call the ode solver as:

```
tspan = [0 10]; % or whatever time interval you want to solve the odes on
x_init = [0;0]; % ot whatever initial conditions you want to use
[T,Y] = ode45(@my_ode,tspan,x_init);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `dce = -gamma*dc;` take x(1) instead of dc as dc is not the value the ode? @am304

Comment: No. `x(1)` is `c`, not `dc/dt`. You need `dc`, it is defined in the previous line so it's valid.

Comment: Oh okay. And is 'Y' storing the values of dc and dce?

Comment: No. `Y` (I should have really called it `X`) is storing the values of `c` and `ce`: `Y = [c;ce];`.

Comment: I think you solved the *actual problem*, but to answer to the OP's title question: no, you can't "use two separate ODE call functions for a system of two differential equations" in this case because the equations are not completely decoupled. This is effectively a second order system. The equations must be integrated simultaneously.